# Lead sharing in community portal with Account manager and Contact

Tags: community

We have the community/partner portal integrated in our org. we have channel managers as internal users with SF license and external users as Partners with Partner Community license.  We have accounts with channel manager as Account manager and have Contacts on that Account as partner.  How do I share Leads owned by the Contact(partner) with the corresponding Account manager(internal user)? My Organization Wide Default(OWD) for Lead is Public Read/Write/transfer.

Really appreciate any advice on this.
Thanks